# AutoMapper sort collection when mapping with EF

Tags: c#, database, automapper, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm using AutoMapper in combinatation with Entity Framework Core to map my entities to my business objects. When saving my objects in a data context to the database the order of the collection changes. I guess because of foreign key relations.

Is there already a way to tell EF Core to keep the order?

For now to keep the order I added a further index property to my table. If this is the way to go I would like to where to put the code in the automapping process?

Edit:

Maybe my question is not clear. e.g. I have a List and I need to store the index in the list to the database. Where's the place to put this kind of code? So that I can make a map from the business object

```
public class MyObject
{
    public List<MyChildObject> Children { get; set; }
}

public class MyChildObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public ICollection<MyChildEntity> Children { get; set; }
}

public class MyChildEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

var myObject = Mapper.Map<MyObject>(myEntity);
// here my object should be exactly the same like before storing
```

Comment: You can specify an order on your query with `OrderBy`.

Comment: Is it the recommended way? It seems like I cannot order an IQueryable.Include by an positioning index in the database.